# How to develop for .NET Micro Framework on Linux?

Tags: linux, netduino, .net-micro-framework

Is there an IDE which will allow me to develop for the .net Micro Framework on Linux?

Maybe [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)?

Comment: Do you mean: Is there an IDE, which will allow me to develop with the .net Micro Framework on Linux? Or do you mean:  Is it possible to use the .net Micro Framework under Linux?

Comment: @Amos the first option

Comment: Edited the question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Netduino forums](http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/21-preview-of-mono-support/):

> Soon, we'll be launching an open source project to port the .NET Micro Framework SDK to Mono for use on Mac and Linux.

They have released the [first alpha release](http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/285-mfdeploy-v41-for-mac-os-x-and-linux-alpha-1/) of MFDeploy for Mono (Mac and Linux).